# GetResponse and GetRequestStream silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, web-services, rest

For some reason I cant use `GetRequestStream` or `GetResponse` in silverlight comes up underlined :S not sure what to use? I am trying to connect to my web service here is where I get the error,

```
string uri = "http://localhost:8002/Service/Customer";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<Customer>");
sb.AppendLine("<FirstName>" + this.textBox1.Text + "</FirstName>");
sb.AppendLine("<LastName>" + this.textBox2.Text + "</LastName>");
sb.AppendLine("</Customer>");
string NewCustomer = sb.ToString();
byte[] arr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(NewCustomer );
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/xml";
req.ContentLength = arr.Length;
Stream reqStrm = req.GetRequestStream();// error here GetRequestStream
reqStrm.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
reqStrm.Close();
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse(); //error here GetRequestStream
MessageBox.Show("Staff Creation: Status " + resp.StatusDescription);
reqStrm.Close();
resp.Close();
```

Does anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight only supports the Asynchronous network access.  There are no synchronous `GetRequestStream` and `GetResponse` methods in Silverlight.  You will need to use the asynchronous methods `BeginGetRequestStream`/`EndGetRequestStream` and `BeginGetResponse`/`EndGetResponse`.

More importantly you will need to get up to speed in how to do things asynchronously in general.  For example something will be calling your above code and expect that after it is complete certain changes will have happpened.  In the asynchronous world that will not be true, the code will return quickly and something will happen later.